# Reduce array of objects to unique keys and add array of values common to that key

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, reduce, ecmascript-5

I would like to group the values of this array by its `car`
key and then push the values common to that car into a values array.

I managed to do it with this but was wondering if there was an simpler way to do it with reduce.

```
const arr = [{
  car: 'audi',
  value: 'black'
}, {
  car: 'audi',
  value: 'expensive'
}, {
  car: 'fiat',
  value: 'red'
}, {
  car: 'fiat',
  value: 'cheap'
}]

// Simple array with unique car
const cars = Array.from(new Set(arr.map(({ car }) => car)))
// Array of objects with unique `car` and an empty `values` array for each
const result = cars.map((car) => ({ car, values: [] }))

// Push to values array the `value` for each car
arr.map((obj) => {
  result.map((res) => {
    if (obj.car === res.car) {
      res.values.push(obj.value)
    }
  })
})

console.log(result)
/*
[{
  car: 'audi',
  values: ['black', 'expensive']
}, {
  car: 'fiat',
  values: ['red', 'cheap']
}]
*/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an object indexed by the `car` name, then iterate over original array, pushing the value to the array on the object:

```js
const arr = [{
  car: 'audi',
  value: 'black'
}, {
  car: 'audi',
  value: 'expensive'
}, {
  car: 'fiat',
  value: 'red'
}, {
  car: 'fiat',
  value: 'cheap'
}];

const carsByName = {};
for (const { car, value } of arr) {
  if (!carsByName[car]) carsByName[car] = { car, value: [] };
  carsByName[car].value.push(value);
}
console.log(Object.values(carsByName));
```

While this *could* be done with `reduce`, it's arguably [not very semantically appropriate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qaGjS7-qWzg) when the accumulator never changes (and is a bit noisy, syntactically):

```js
const arr = [{
  car: 'audi',
  value: 'black'
}, {
  car: 'audi',
  value: 'expensive'
}, {
  car: 'fiat',
  value: 'red'
}, {
  car: 'fiat',
  value: 'cheap'
}];

const carsByName = arr.reduce((a, { car, value }) => {
  if (!a[car]) a[car] = { car, value: [] };
  a[car].value.push(value);
  return a;
}, {});
console.log(Object.values(carsByName));
```

Comment: Thanks, looks great, could I do `[carsByName]` instead of Object.values(carsByName)?

Comment: That would give you an array containing a single object, with that object being indexed by car name. If that data structure is what you want, go for it, but it's not what your expected output in the question was.

Comment: You are right, many thanks for the code works great

Answer (score 2):

Just use reduce for it. Keep in `acc` the array of cars with keys `car` and `values`. And then map it. I mean:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    car: "audi",
    value: "black",
  },
  {
    car: "audi",
    value: "expensive",
  },
  {
    car: "fiat",
    value: "red",
  },
  {
    car: "fiat",
    value: "cheap",
  },
];

const result = Object.entries(
  arr.reduce((acc, { car, value }) => {
    if (acc[car]) {
      return {
        ...acc,
        [car]: [...acc[car], value],
      };
    }

    return { ...acc, [car]: [value] };
  }, [])
).map(([car, values]) => ({ car, values }));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to group the items by `car`, and then, [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a list of objects having `car` and its `values`:

```js
const arr = [{
  car: 'audi',
  value: 'black'
}, {
  car: 'audi',
  value: 'expensive'
}, {
  car: 'fiat',
  value: 'red'
}, {
  car: 'fiat',
  value: 'cheap'
}]

let result = arr.reduce((acc,item) => {
  const values = acc[item.car];
  acc[item.car] = values ? [...values, item.value] : [item.value];
  return acc;
}, {});

result = Object.entries(result).map(([car, values]) => ({car,values}));

console.log(result)
```